# add animation to already created asp.net app

Tags: css, ajax

Hi i have already created my asp.net app and its running perfectly except we recruited a new member and he started on this new app and he is using bootstrap animations and templates and all... while i didnt i used css myself cause i tried to personolise it just like they want any way now my boss was amazed with what bootstrap can do an all and now i want to add transitions and cool css,ajax stuff to my app any links or methods to help please im BURNING INSIDE.

```
    please help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you need to update your project to use boostrap, then you need to move all the styles you added to a stylesheet file, and call them as needed (that is separate from bootstrap, just to make it more easy when you need to change styles). Besides that, if you want to use Bootstrap, it's simple, just add the boostrap files (styles, JS) and then use them as explained in the Boostrap website. Also, you can customize them as you want, but those components and classes will make the magic to make your website compatible with cross browsing and devices.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Hope that helps!